# Is there a guideline for accessibility (such as 508 compliance) in email correspondence?

Tags: email, html-email, section508

I am building an application that will have a number of notifications going out via email. Is there a guideline on making the content of the email accessible to screen readers and other similar tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bit late for you, but your question is still relevant today. You can start with W.c.a.g. guidelines, but keep in mind not everything is applicable in email.

The email accessibility checker I developed is optimized for email HTML, and may be easier to use: http://www.accessible-email.org

It tests your email for different accessibility feautures which are possible in email and it will tell you what accessibility features are missing. (if any)

Answer (score 2):

You raise a good point.  There has been a web accessibility guidelines for a long time now (since back in the late 90s I think) however email accessibility guidelines have been largely ignored.

While accessibility can be determined by mail clients in terms of how they render HTML emails (which [people are trying to rectify](http://www.email-standards.org/) similar to a browser standard), it is important to design your emails so that they are accessible for all display technologies.

A few have attempted to set some guidelines:

- [The TEN Standard](http://www.headstar.com/ten/)
- [Dave Chaffey](http://davechaffey.com/Total-E-mail-Marketing/Accessible-E-newsletter-guidelines?)

Hope that helps.